# Spark Local unable to read file in local directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning spark and I am very new to it, I am trying to execute some spark jobs using a python file, and I am executing the file using spark-submit. When I execute the command, the job crashes apparently due to it not being able to read the file. This is how my python file looks

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("FriendsByAge")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    age = int(fields[2])
    numFriends = int(fields[3])
    return (age, numFriends)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/data/fakefriends.csv",10000)
rdd = lines.map(parseLine)
totalsByAge = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
averagesByAge = totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
results = averagesByAge.collect()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

when I executed the above code I am getting the following error.

Full stack trace:

```
C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.16_9\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows;C:\jdk\jdk-21\bin;C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\bin;C:\winutils\bin;C:\Users\dhiri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dhiri\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\dhiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows;C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\bin;C:\jdk\jdk-21\bin;D:\Idea\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3\bin;;C:\winutils\bin;
PS D:\SparkCourse> spark-submit friends-by-age.py
C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:65: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
24/02/03 15:58:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 20 more
24/02/03 15:58:19 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SparkCourse\friends-by-age.py", line 16, in <module>
    results = averagesByAge.collect()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (DESKTOP-RCUFERQ.mshome.net executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 20 more
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///D:/SparkCourse/data/fakefriends.csv",10000)
```

I suggest you simplify your code and instead using `parseLine` switch to

`spark.read.csv(file_path, sep ='\t', header = False)`